# How to understand the result of Mathematica's CoefficientList?

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix of coefficients for a quadratic form:

CoefficientList[1 + a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]

$$\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & c \\ 0 & b & 0 \\ a & 0 & 0 \\\end{array}\right)\end{align*}$$

why this represent a quadratic form?

CoefficientList[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y + f, {x, y}]

$$\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} f & e & c \\ d & b & 0 \\ a & 0 & 0 \\\end{array}\right)\end{align*}$$

Comment: Why not read the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientList.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `CoefficientList[1 + a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]` is a matrix because your polynomial has two variables, $x$ and $y$. The matrix consists of the coefficients $c_{ij}$ where $i$ and $j$ range from $0$ to $2$ and $c_{ij}$ is the coefficient of $x^i y^j$ in the given polynomial.